# UnauthorizedError: No authorization token was found

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

In My MERN application SIGNUP,SIGNIN is working fine, but when am trying to view my profile on clicking about page then getting an error like "No authorization token was found" for backend am using issignedIn and isAuthenticated middleware, those person who SignIn application who are able to see about us page.

[image: Token Generate when login page]

ABoutus.js

```
 const callAboutPage = async()=>{
        try{
            const res = await fetch('/about',{
                method:"GET",
                headers:{
                    Accept:'application/json',
                    'Content-Type':'application/json' 
                },
                credentials:"include"
            })

            const data = await res.json();
            console.log(data)
            // if(!res.status === 200){
            //     const error = new Error(res.error)
            //     throw error;
            // }

        }
        catch(err){
            console.log(err);
            history.push('/login')
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
      callAboutPage();
    }, [])



auth.js/controller



   //PROTECTED ROUTE
    exports.isSignedIn = expressJwt({
        secret: process.env.SECRET,
        algorithms: ['RS256'],
        userProperty: "Auth"
    });
    
    //CUSTOM MIDDLEWARE
    exports.isAuthenticated = (req, res, next) => {
        let checker = req.profile && req.Auth && req.profile._id == req.Auth._id;
        if (!checker) {
            return res.status(403).json({
                error: "ACCESS DENIED"
            });
        }
        next();
    };
```

Route

```
router.get('/about',isSignedIn,isAuthenticated,(req,res)=>{
    res.send("A protected Route")
});
```

Comment: Are you sending the token with your request?

Comment: Please send authorization token from the frontend

Comment: Thanks for giving your valuable Time, Please checkout, I have attached Token generated Pic . which will get when I login my page